# Minimize the width of left column to focus on right column of a row HTML / in-line CSS / Markdown

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, markdown

Looking to allocate most of the row space to line up with the container to the right column of a row. I've used 
Column1
Column2

This seems to resolve the issue on some online HTML editors, but for some reason, it has no effect on the internal editor I'm using which is mainly focused on MarkDown / HTML / In-Line CSS

Is there a way that this can be done preferably using in-Line CSS?

```
<div class="main-container" style="display: flex;">
   <div class="image-container">
      <img
         src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/coMv1dl31PCfEs6essJoEUwVryaqKHKQvENdZ_WYpN-PXa8Qfitkg3grQxIVN22W5A"
         hspace="50" width="150" height="150">
   </div>
   <div class="content-container" style="width: 600px;">
      <h3>Subject Title</h3>
      <h4>Subject Description</h4>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <p>
               <center><span style="font-weight:bold">Sample Service</span></center>
               </p>
            </td>
            <td>Sample Service Details Will be listed here!!!!!!!!!!!</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <p>
               <center><span style="font-weight:bold">Contact Us</span></center>
               </p>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px;">
               <ul style="padding-left: 15px; margin: 0;">
                  <li style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                     <a href="mailto:Sample@sample.com​">Email Sample</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a>Skype: Sample Contact</a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```